# Admob transparent in ListActivity

Tags: android, admob, adview

AdView displays after a few seconds but it is transparent and listView is taking up whole screen.  Looked everywhere but cannot get Adview to behave.  Can you see what I am doing wrong so the ListView is making space for the Adview?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_with_adview);
}
```

activity_with_adview.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/black" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: example of problem]

Answer (score 0):

I was laying a list fragment over the top.  Thinking that the fragment was a list.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_with_adview);

    if (TradiesBillingManager.hasPurchasedDiary()) {

        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
            DiaryFragment list = new DiaryFragment();
            list.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, list).commit();
        }

    } else {

        DiaryFragment list = new DiaryFragment();
        list.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, list).commit();
    }

}
```

activity_with_adview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/adView"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a relative layout and the view that you declare the last will be painted on top of the other views. If you want to put ads above the list view you will have to declare the AdView widget below the LinearLayout in the xml file